# Add a Data-test-id attribute to a <td> in my Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `Table`, `Textarea` and a `Button`. When a user types inside the `Textarea` and then clicks on my `Button` the text gets added to the `Table` as a row with following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
    $('#CustomButton').click(function() {
        $('#CustomPickedTable tbody').append(
            $('<tr/>',
             {
            click: function() {
                    $(this).remove();
                    },
                html: $('<td/>', {
                    text: $('#CustomQuestionText').val()
                })
            })
        );
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

When a user types inside the `TextArea` and then clicks on the `Button` is that my `Table Tbody` gets this `<td>What user typed..</td>` What I would like is that my table gets `<td data-test-id="5">what user typed..</td>.`

Is there any solutions for that in my jquery so my `<td>` gets an data-test-id attribute?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way

```
$('#CustomButton').click(function() {
    $('#CustomPickedTable tbody').append(
        $('<tr/>', {
            html: $("<td />", {
                html: $("#CustomQuestionText").val(),
                'data-attr-id': 5

            })
        })
    );
    return false;
});
```

- [**Demo:** Working Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/rhAu5/2/)
- [**Demo:** With `remove`](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/rhAu5/4/)

Comment: I cant' get it to work with click: function() {$(this).remove();

Answer (score 2):

try

```
 {
                click : function() {$(this).remove();},
                html: $('<td/>', {text: $('#CustomQuestionText').val()},
                attr : { 'data-test-id' : 'whatever' }
  }
```

[**Reference**](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Comment: I tried it but in some strange way its not working could you take a look at it and edit my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jmdy9/

Comment: @RammtinAvar, This solution defines `attr` as the attribute not `data-test-id`. Check my answer

Comment: @RammtinAvar your given jsfiddle is not even working with your code. first make that perfect

Comment: it was beacuse I added your code line example, but here it is http://jsfiddle.net/jmdy9/1/ without it :)

Answer (score 0):

declare a dynamic id vairable and get table rows count in it, then apply it to td element id

```
var dynamicId = document.getElementById("yourtable").getElementsByTagName("TR").length;

html: $('<td data-test-id="' + dynamicId + '"/>', {
                text: $('#CustomQuestionText').val()
            })
```